# Unable to solve the equation due to inconsistent variable

Tags: equation-solving

How do I solve this for w?
I know that phi1 and phi2 cannot be solved for but shouldn't 'w' be solved?

This is the error I see
Reduce::inex: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Reduce require exact input, providing Reduce with an exact version of the system may help.

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"]
G = 0.8*10^11;
d = 0.1;
l = 0.6;
J = Pi*d^4/32;
kt = G*J/l;

I1 = 22.6;
I2 = 5.66;
P1 = ( {
    {1, 0},
    {-I1*w^2, 1}
   } );
P2 = ( {
    {1, 0},
    {-I2*w^2, 1}
   } );
F2 = ( {
    {1, 1/kt},
    {0, 1}
   } );
U1 = P1;
U2 = P2.F2;
Trans = Rationalize[U2.U1] // MatrixForm
T1 = 0;
T2 = 0;
Simplify[Reduce[({{phi1}, {0}}) == Trans.({{phi2}, {0}}), w], 
 Assumptions -> phi2 != 0]
```

Comment: do `Rationalize[U2.U1, 0]` and get rid of the `MatrixForm`

Answer (score 1):

you need to apply the `phi2 != 0` using `Simplify` after `Reduce`.

```
Simplify[Reduce[ ({{phi1}, {0}}) == Trans.({{phi2}, {0}})  , w], 
 Assumptions -> phi2 != 0]
```

> phi1 == phi2 && (w == -2 Sqrt[2] || w == 2 Sqrt[2])

Note the error message you report is coming from some old definition. There are no inexact coefficients in what you show here. Restart your kernel.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for responding. My actual trans matrix is
trans = { {1 - 0.0000172651 w^2, 7.63944*10^-7},
 {-5.66 w^2 - 22.6 w^2 (1 - 4.32392*10^-6 w^2), 1. - 4.32392*10^-6 w^2}
}

It still gives that error with this matrix

Comment: It gives you the error because you have inexact numbers. Any number you write with a decimal point is inexact.

Comment: Eventually, this should have solved the following using matrix multiplication
Solve[-28.26*w^2 + 0.00009772062576260581*w^4 == 0, w]

which gives 
{w -> -537.766}, {w -> 0.}, {w -> 0.}, {w -> 537.766}}

But it doesn't go further till this step. Could you tell what am I doing wrong and what should I be doing?

Comment: Don't use inexact numbers as input to a symbolic method like `Solve` or `Reduce`. `28.26` is inexact. `2826/100` is exact.

Comment: edit the question with the actual problem you are having. Don't add new material that completely changes the question through comments.

Comment: You can use [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) to convert inexact numbers to exact numbers. To guarantee that the conversion will always work use `Rationalize[#, 0]&`

Comment: I tried using rationalize. It doesn't give me the inexact error but it still doesn't solve for w. I have also tried using just variables commenting the first few lines that assign values but no luck. it doesn't end up giving the value of w in terms of these variables.